# Django filter permission with condition?

Tags: django, permissions, filtering

Used to get all permissions for user with
`perms = request.user.get_all_permissions()`.
Now I have a wrappper model:

`Class PermWrap(models.Model):

      perm = models.OneToOneField(Permission)`

Now, I have a condition that if it is True, the user permissions should be filtered to these only in this wrapper table. 
Means, since django returns permissions as a set, I could do

`if condition: 
    perms.intersection(build_perms_from_this_table)`

But filtering like that using permissions codes names seems bad to me.
Is there a way to get user permissions as a queryset, so filtering will be in the db?